# How to create Circular SeekBar for count the cycle in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to create a circular seek bar which tells the number of cycles complete. I have a sample of IOS but I want to create the same as in Android(JAVA or Kotlin). Kindly guide me, how to create a circular seek bar the same as IOS.   https://github.com/HamzaGhazouani/HGCircularSlider/blob/master/Screenshots/Circular.gif

Comment: Are you trying to make it yourself? You can use a library directly or use these as samples to make your own. https://github.com/feeeei/CircleSeekbar or https://github.com/devadvance/circularseekbar

Comment: Can you provide me a solution? because I tried myself, but no luck.